# angular google map polyline with direction arrow head marker

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I need a path connecting a few locations with arrow heads at my markers.

Currently I'm drawing polyline, but it doesn't show arrows indicating directions.

HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='routeMap.center' zoom='routeMap.zoom' events="routeMap.events" refresh="refreshMap" control="routeMap.control">
    <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="activity in activityFeed" idKey="activity.id" coords="activity.coordinates" events="routeMap.markersEvents"  control="routeMap.markersControl">
        <ui-gmap-polylines models="markers" stroke="stroke" path="markers" events="routeMap.markersEvents"></ui-gmap-polylines>
    </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

The markers array consists of dictionaries of latitude, longitude keys.

I read this is not possible with polylines with current libraries. But I believe there has got to be some work around for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specify that in your Polyline configuration:

HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-polyline 
ng-repeat="p in map.polylines" 
path="p.path" 
stroke="p.stroke" 
visible='p.visible' 
geodesic='p.geodesic' 
fit="false" 
editable="p.editable" 
draggable="p.draggable" 
icons='p.icons'>
</ui-gmap-polyline>
```

js:

```
  $scope.map.polylines = [
            {
              id: 1,
              path: [
              ],
              stroke: {
                color: '#04B0FF',
                weight: 2
              },
              editable: false,
              draggable: false,
              geodesic: true,
              visible: true,
              icons: [
                {
                  icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
                  },
                  offset: '25px',
                  repeat: '50px'
                }
              ]
            }
    ]
```

You can also refer to this [Demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/demo)